# Ruby green shoes timer

Tags: ruby, timer, shoes, green-shoes

I'm building this popup countdown timer for a game. The issue is I can't figure out how to update the the animate so that the display changes too. It works so far, but you can't see the numbers changing. It blends into the 00:00. I'm pretty positive it works so far just having trouble with this change. This is done with green shoes. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

```
#Timer button used for creating a countdown timer for the game.
    #Game ends when timer is zero.
    flow width: 80, height: 0.2 do
    button 'Timer', width: 1.0, height: 1.0 do
        window do
        def time_change!
           @clock = '%02d:%02d' % [@second / 60, @second % 60]
           if(@second == 0)
            alert "game is over"
            @clock = '00:00'
                close()
            para @clock, size: 50, stroke: black
           end
         end

         background whitesmoke
         @clock = '00:00'
         para @clock, size: 50, stroke: black


         @second = 10

        animate(1) do
            @second -= 1
            time_change!
            para @clock, size: 50, stroke: black

        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you have any references that discuss defining a method inside a window block?  I'm aware that def's attach themselves to whatever the current class is, and I know that self inside a window block is the window, but it does not necessarily follow that the current class is the window, e.g. in an `instance_eval` block, self is the caller, while the current class is the caller's singleton class.  On the other hand, inside a class, say `class Dog`, but outside any def's, self = Dog and the current class is Dog as well.  Your code executes without error, so `self=window=current_class`.

Comment: I'm actually new to ruby so I took a guess on that and you're right it does run without error. The interesting thing is I end up getting method errors for @p.text and seg faults at times for  trying to call instance variables inside a para call. Sadly, green shoes is a bit useless compared to current shoes but it's the one my group choice to use. I'll make that method outside of the block this time and see if that changes anything

Comment: Okay.  I used regular Shoes(walkabout) to answer your question, and it looks terrible in OSX.  The window title is blurry, as well as the min, max, and close buttons.  It's as if someone took a picture of an OSX window with a terrible cell phone, then converted it to a .png, then used that to represent a window.  There are also other problems: the text in the elements title, subtitle, and caption are cut off at the baseline.  Many years ago, I messed around with wxRuby, and it was pretty nice.  Unfortunately, the maintainer gave up on wxRuby.

Comment: how do you install the regular shoes on ubuntu? green shoes is really bad to be honest. I had trouble installing shoes on ubuntu

Comment: There's a linux download here: http://shoesrb.com/downloads/.  Did you try that? I had the opposite problem: I've tried installing Green Shoes a couple of times over the years and never could get it installed on OSX.

Comment: your solution worked for green shoes too. I wonder why I was getting errors with .text calls. I guess you can use .text calls inside of a flow, but not outside of a flow

Comment: For future searchers, *and I know that self inside a window block is the window*--Actually, Shoes Rules has an example with a main window and a child window, and self inside a window block is a second instance of a Shoes.app object.  I guess when you call close on that second instance, it closes that App object's window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the text of the current para which displays the clock:

```
Shoes.app do
  flow do 
    button 'Timer', width: 100, height: 50 do
      window width: 200, height: 100 do  #Open a child window when the button is clicked
        seconds = 3
        tenths = 0
        clock =  '%02d:%02d'

        flow do
          @p = para clock % [seconds, tenths], #Assign the clock para to an instance variable, 
            size: 50,                          #which will make the variable visible outside this block.
            stroke: black
        end

        a = animate(10) do  #Upate the clock every 1/10 of a second.
          tenths -= 1

          if tenths < 0
            tenths  = 9
            seconds -= 1
          end

          @p.text = clock % [seconds, tenths]  #Replace the clock text.

          if seconds == 0 and tenths == 0
            a.stop
            alert("game over")
            close   #=>self.close where self is the window whose block contains this code
          end
        end #animate

      end #window
    end #button
  end #flow
end #app
```

To verify that the clock is actualy showing each time increment, you can slow things down by changing `animate(10)` to `animate(1)`.